# What is the showS trick in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have seen references to the `showS` trick to build strings (e.g., in [this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/2244)), but I have never seen a good description of it.

What is the showS trick?

Comment: Looking at the answers here, a concise summary might be: the "`showS` trick" is to turn an inefficient (`O(n^2)`) left-associated string concatenation into an efficient (`O(n)`) right-associated string concatenation by turning strings into (prepend) continuations and then composing the continuations.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the standard library, `ShowS` is defined as:

```
type ShowS = String -> String
```

This is a [*difference list*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list).
The trick is that a string `xs` is represented as a `ShowS` by the function that prepends it to any other list: `(xs ++)`. This allows efficient concatenation, avoiding the problems of nested left-associative concatenation (i.e. `((as ++ bs) ++ cs) ++ ds`). For example:

```
hello = ("hello" ++)
world = ("world" ++)

-- We can "concatenate" ShowS values simply by composing them:
helloworld = hello . world

-- and turn them into Strings by passing them an empty list:
helloworld' = helloworld ""
```

It's called `ShowS` because it's used in the implementation of the standard `Show` typeclass to allow efficient `show`ing of large, deeply-nested structures; as well as `show`, you can implement `showsPrec`, which has the type:

```
showsPrec :: (Show a) => Int -> a -> ShowS
```

This allows handling of operator precedence, and returns a `ShowS` value. The standard instances implement this instead of `show` for efficiency; `show a` is then defined in terms of it, as `showsPrec 0 a ""`. (This default definition is in the `Show` typeclass itself, so you can just implement `showsPrec` for a complete instance.)

Comment: Link:
ShowS is in the Text.Show module of the base package at
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Text-Show.html

Answer (score 11):

`showS` uses the difference list approach to efficiently concatenate individual components of the shown value.  The function takes the value to be shown, *and* a string to append to the result.  The appended string is passed all the way down to the right-most sub-value until it reaches a leaf, where it is actually appended.

There's a description of difference lists (including `showS`) here http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list