# Why does Haskell's showList function return ShowS

Tags: haskell, lambda

I am trying to create a type for simple key/value pairs, that can be converted to a URL query. So I created the following ADT:

```
data Target where
    (:=>) :: String -> String -> Target

instance Show Target where
    show (a :=> b) = a ++ "=" ++ b
    showList (xs) = (\y -> intercalate "&" $ map show xs)
```

When I run it in ghci it works exactly how I want:

```
ghci>["id" :=> "123", "color" :=> "red"]
id=123&color=red
it :: [Target]
```

My question is: Why do I need the lambda in `showList`?  I tried to `show y` and it just prints an empty string.  What is the purpose of returning a `ShowS` when the argument is just empty? Or maybe a better question, to what is the `showS` function applied in this case?

Answer (score 1):

`ShowS` exists to allow for optimization of concatenation and concatenation by composition. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197913/what-is-the-shows-trick-in-haskell) for more information on `ShowS`.

For your example, instead of ignoring `y`, you may want to retain the concatenation benefits with something like this:

```haskell
showList (xs) = ((intercalate "&" $ map show xs) ++)
```