# Semantics of show w.r.t. escape characters

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following examples (`λ>` = ghci, `$` = shell):

```
λ> writeFile "d" $ show "d"
$ cat d
"d"

λ> writeFile "d" "d"
$ cat d
d

λ> writeFile "backslash" $ show "\\"
$ cat backslash
"\\"

λ> writeFile "backslash" "\\"
$ cat backslash
\

λ> writeFile "cat" $ show "" -- U+1F408
$ cat cat
"\128008"

λ> writeFile "cat" ""
$ cat cat
```

I understand that another way of `"\128008"` is just another way of representing
`""` in Haskell source code.
My question is: why does the `""` example behave like the backslash instead of
like `"d"`? Since it is a printable character, shouldn't it behave like
a letter?

More generally, what is the rule to determine whether the character will be
shown as a printable character or as an escape code? I looked at [Section 6.3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1270006.3)
in the Haskell 2010 Language report but it doesn't specify the exact behaviour.

Comment: Related: [How to hack GHCi (or Hugs) so that it prints Unicode chars unescaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5535512/2682729).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL:DR; Printable characters inside the ASCII range (0-127) will be `show`n as graphic characters.* Everything else will be escaped.

* Except for double quotes (as they're used for string delimiters) and
backslashes (because they're needed for escaping).

Let's have a look at the source code to figure this one out!

Since we have `String = [Char]`, we should hunt for `instance Show Char` in
the source. It can be found 
[here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html).
It is defined as:

```
-- | @since 2.01
instance  Show Char  where
    showsPrec _ '\'' = showString "'\\''"
    showsPrec _ c    = showChar '\'' . showLitChar c . showChar '\''

    showList cs = showChar '"' . showLitString cs . showChar '"'
```

So showing a `String` (using `showList`) is basically a wrapper around
`ShowLitString`, and showing a `Char` is a wrapper around `ShowLitChar`.
Let's look at those functions.

```
showLitString :: String -> ShowS
-- | Same as 'showLitChar', but for strings
-- It converts the string to a string using Haskell escape conventions
-- for non-printable characters. Does not add double-quotes around the
-- whole thing; the caller should do that.
-- The main difference from showLitChar (apart from the fact that the
-- argument is a string not a list) is that we must escape double-quotes
showLitString []         s = s
showLitString ('"' : cs) s = showString "\\\"" (showLitString cs s)
showLitString (c   : cs) s = showLitChar c (showLitString cs s)
   -- [explanatory comments ...]
```

As you might've expected, `showLitString` is mostly a wrapper around
`showLitChar`. 
[Note: If you're unfamiliar with the `ShowS` type, this is a good
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9198124/2682729) to understand why
it might be useful.]
Not quite what we were looking for, so let us go to `showLitChar` (I've
omitted parts of the definition which aren't relevant to the question).

```
-- | Convert a character to a string using only printable characters,
-- using Haskell source-language escape conventions.  For example:
-- [...]
showLitChar                :: Char -> ShowS
showLitChar c s | c > '\DEL' =  showChar '\\' (protectEsc isDec (shows (ord c)) s)
-- ^ Pattern matched for cat
showLitChar '\DEL'         s =  showString "\\DEL" s
showLitChar '\\'           s =  showString "\\\\" s
-- ^ Pattern matched for backslash
showLitChar c s | c >= ' '   =  showChar c s
-- ^ Pattern matched for d
-- Some more escape codes
showLitChar '\a'           s =  showString "\\a" s
-- similarly for '\b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t', '\v' etc.
-- showLitChar ... = ...
```

Now you see where the problem is. `ord c` is an `int`, and the first is taken
for all non-ASCII characters (`ord '\DEL' == 127`).
For characters in the ASCII range, the printable characters are printed and
the rest are escaped. For characters outside it, all of them are escaped.

The code doesn't answer the "why" part of the question. The answer to that
(I think) is in the very first comment that we saw:

```
-- | @since 2.01
instance  Show Char  where
```

<s>If I were guessing, this behaviour has been kept around for maintain backwards
compatibility.</s> I don't need to guess: see the comments for some good answers to this.

#### Bonus

We can do a `git blame` online using GHC's Github mirror ;). Let's see
when this code was written
([blame link](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blame/bc761ad9c65c7aa62d38db39c59a6c0ae59c8ab8/libraries/base/GHC/Show.hs#L360)).
The relevant [commit](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/fbf9b826362cc72631e99045e3cc6ab1bf4d5b1f) is 15 years old (!). However, it does mention Unicode.

The functionality to distinguish between different types of Unicode characters
is present in the `Data.Char` module. Looking at the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Unicode.html#isPrint):

```
isPrint    c = iswprint (ord c) /= 0

foreign import ccall unsafe "u_iswprint"
  iswprint :: Int -> Int
```

If you trace the commit which introduced `iswprint`, you'll land up 
[here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/2b179f023136bb22103856f74e44de281f31be82). That commit was made 13 years ago.
<s>Maybe there was sufficient code written in those two years which they didn't
want to break? I don't know. If some GHC developer could shed more light on this,
that'd be awesome :).</s> Daniel Wagner and Paul Johnson in the comments have pointed out a very good reason for this - operating with non-Unicode systems must've been a high priority (~15 years ago) as Unicode was relatively new back then.

Comment: The output of `Show` is 7-bit clean, a nice property for inclusion in/attachment to email because that means it doesn't need an extra round of escaping, nice because ASCII is available almost everywhere, and nice because many popular encodings agree on what bytes to use for 7-bit clean text.

Comment: Is that just a useful side effect of the current implementation or one of the actual justifications for having it the way it is?

Comment: That is the folklore justification that I have heard repeated often. I don't have a canonical source to support it, though.

Comment: 15 years ago being compatible with non-unicode systems was more important than it is now. However there is also the bonus that when you read an escaped string you can see exactly what is there, including control characters. That is useful because different strings can wind up looking the same when printed. The escaped version lets you know what is really going on.

Comment: @Paul Johnson, good point! Having never really written code that needs to interop with old code, I didn't think of that.