# chr 232 doesn't return character è

Tags: haskell

The evaluation of `chr 232` returns `'\232'` instead of `'è'`.

Of course, I expected `(chr . ord) 'è'` to return `'è'`. Instead, I got `'\232'`

Could someone explain what's happening, here ?

Comment: `'\232'` is `'è'`

Comment: Try `putStrLn [chr 232]`. Don't use `show` for `Char`s if you want to output the raw `Char` as-is. `print` implicitly calls `show`, and GHCi implicitly calls `print`.

Comment: Closely related: [*Semantics of show w.r.t. escape characters*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48846437/2751851)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you @duplode.

Comment: Interesting to know. Thank you, @chi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell will show as *representation* of a character a backslash (`\`) followed with the decimal codepoint for most non-ASCII characters. The *representation* of a `Char` will also be surrounded with single quotes (`'…'`).

If you want to print the *content* of a string, you can work with [**`putChar :: Char -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putChar):

```
Prelude Data.Char> putChar (chr 232)
èPrelude Data.Char>
```

or you can wrap it in a singleton list and use `putStrLn` to print a line with that character:

```
Prelude Data.Char> putStrLn [chr 232]
è
```